# There's an grammar bug in Docs' "Still have a question?"

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

They say a picture is worth a thousand words:

[image: Still have a ActiveRecord Migrations question ?]

Need I say more?

Comment: Related: *[Pluralization Bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/63791#63791)*

Comment: @Peter Lol, indeed :D

Comment: @Hack Why edit out? It's for irony indeed.

Comment: Yes you do. Carry on, please. I am african. What was your point?

Comment: @SugatoSengupta a double consecutive vowel is incorrect grammar.

Comment: @4castle: Yeah, shouldn't have commented without reading through the question. Realized it later. My bad.

Comment: STILL HAZ MOAR QUESTIONS?...[Ask Question]

Comment: Am I the only one who finds it amusing that a question complaining about a grammatical error on the site has a grammatical error in the title?

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel You're about the tenth person to notice that. Yes, it was deliberate. Irony, my friend. It's a beautiful thing.

Comment: Since I don't have editing privileges: transcribing the image text has the advantage of allowing screen-reader users to see the text in question. Check your privilege, this picture is only worth a thousand words for some.

Comment: @ArtOfCode Didn't see any other comments, which is why I did! Wasn't sure if it was a mistake or not

Comment: @AmaniKilumanga That's what image alt text is for. Which, if you had checked, you would have seen.

Comment: @ArtOfCode checked the edit history now, my bad. I might have noticed it earlier if I had editing privileges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.

Comment: I see my Populist coming!

Comment: Oh no. No longer I do.

Comment: [Now there is a new grammar-related issue.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332302/i-still-have-question-about-grammar-in-documentations-still-have-a-question)

Answer (score 41):

An alternative:

> Still have a question about this topic?

This is just to cover all bases, because topics come in a variety of phrasing styles.

Answer (score 40):

I propose this wording:

> Still have a question about {topic-name-there}?

Comment: There are few topic names that sound really weird like this. Why not just `Still have a question about this topic?` and don't even bother with inserting the topic name.

Comment: `Still have a question about Compile and run your first Java program?`

Comment: Quotes could help. `Still have a question about "Compile and run your first Java program"?`

Comment: Still sounds like you're talking to ELIZA. *What makes you believe "I propose this wording"?*