# I still have a question about grammar in Documentation's "Still have a question?"

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, spelling

Previously on Stack Overflow Meta, there was [a grammar bug relating to `a` and `an` before topic names](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329147/theres-an-grammar-bug-in-docs-still-have-a-question).

Now, the article has been removed fully, and that is bad grammar. Here's an image with the issue:

[image]

You can find this issue on any Documentation page, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/103/intent), when you scroll all the way down to the bottom. I've archived it on [the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20160812031626/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/103/intent) for when this bug gets fixed.

Is this intended? What would we change it to?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332334/still-have-question-about-ask-question?noredirect=1#comment382789_332334

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sentence will be changed to "Still have a question about $Topic?" on Monday.

I have the change ready to go locally, but I have a thing about not pushing non-essential code to production on a weekend. :)

Comment: Wouldn't it take 6-8 weeks?

Comment: I mean, I *can* hold this back a while...

Comment: @AdamLear you mean bad grammar is non-essential?!?!?! Better not go to [English.SE](http://english.stackexchange.com/) anytime soon :)

Comment: @psubsee2003 i dont no wat ur talking about

Comment: We need proof before it takes 6-8 weeks

Comment: @Peanut http://i.stack.imgur.com/l6EAu.png #sadface

Comment: The variable is `$Title$`, not `$Topic`. It's a trap!

Comment: @psubsee2003 Watch those `?!?!?!` strings unless you don't want to have the same fate as Adam

Answer (score 1):

[A duplicate of this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332334/still-have-question-about-ask-question) noted that we could change it to:

> Still have questions about Declarations and Assignments?

Comment: So this is a [pluralization bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236746/what-is-the-story-of-jeff-atwood-and-the-pluralization-bug) .... ?

Comment: @rene Not exactly, just suggesting that could be what it was changed to. It was originally supposed to have an article.