# "Still have question about ____ ? Ask Question"

Tags: bug, documentation

Can this be reworded in documentation:

[image]

When you go to a topic and scroll all the way down within the topic you are met with this.  Could it be changed to read:

"Still have questions about Topic X?"

Need an 's' in question to make questions?

Comment: I think this was just asked earlier today.... looking

Comment: Yep found it here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332302/i-still-have-question-about-grammar-in-documentations-still-have-a-question